# 3g Modem not auto connecting with console mode but auto connects while in desktop!

Tags: usb, networkmanager, modem, 3g

I have strange behaviour.
I have USB 3G Modem and it doesnt auto-connect, yet that's what I want. I am just in headless mode; I'm trying "nmcli" and it doesn't work at all.
But when I start desktop X11 system, it also starts nm-applet and it auto connects to 3G.
Why so?

```
root@chip:~# nmcli g
STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN
connected  full          enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled
```

```
root@chip:~# nmcli c
NAME            UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE
Ruter           00d82c8e-6ef2-49b7-b1ac-a66c303a560e  802-11-wireless  wlan0
ZZ              32f8fa94-35d6-4a51-9a5d-5c500270a0ed  gsm              --
usb0_linklocal  3c8ee1db-c6b3-4db6-8bfc-4e94e72cab17  802-3-ethernet   --
```

ZZ is 3G connection
Wi-Fi is auto connecting, but 3G no!
Also:

```
root@chip:~# nmcli c up ZZ
Error: Connection activation failed.
```

But nm-applet works fine and it automatically connects to 3G.

Answer (score 0):

Well wvdial helped!
I also added

```
auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet wvdial
```

to `/etc/network/interfaces`

By the way, I'm using C.H.I.P; you can do this also on Raspberry.